# Kendo toolbar button not firing click event after being enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my logic, here I am trying to disable the save changes button and prevent click event on it if the user enters a duplicate value and enable it again if the user changes the values but after enabling it the update / save event does not occur am I doing something wrong? This is my code

```
function OnChange(data) {
    //data.preventDefault();
    $(".k-grid-save-changes")
        .attr("role", "button")
        .removeClass("k-state-disabled")
        //.addClass("k-grid-save-changes")
        .click(function () {
            return true;
        });
    //console.log("data", data.items["0"].ProviderTypeName);

    var name = data.items["0"].ProviderTypeName;
    var Id = data.items["0"].Id;
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    //console.log("Grid ", grid);
    grid.tbody.find('>tr').each(
        function () {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
            //console.log(dataItem.ProviderTypeName)
            if (dataItem.ProviderTypeName == name && dataItem.Id != Id) {
                $(this).css('background', 'red');
                $(".k-grid-save-changes")
                    //.removeClass("k-grid-save-changes")
                    .addClass("k-state-disabled")
                    //.removeAttr("role")
                    .click(function () {
                        return false;
                    });
                    }
                });
}
```

This is where is call the on change event

```
.Events(events => events.RequestStart("OnRequestStart").Change("OnChange").RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd").Error("onError"))
```

If I remove the "return false;" it is working as expected but this allows duplicated values to be saved. So I have used this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly in your code you do exactly what you mention as a problem. At every change you disable the save functionality with the return false. You don't enable it again at any point.

If you add an event handler to the button then you have to undo it at a later point. Since though I don't believe that the validation should occur at the change event but at the button click I would suggest to use the grid Save event where you could iterate dataSource.data() of your grid (much better) do your check and if anything happens return false.

One other way to go since you probably want the css effect with the background is to keep your code and discard the click event. Just set a flag that you could use in the save event. Something like this:

```
if(// your control){
   $(this).css('background', 'red');
    duplicatedValue = true;
}else{
   .removeClass("k-grid-save-changes");
   duplicatedValue = false;
}
```

And in the save event

```
function onSave(){
   if(duplicatedValue){
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped

Comment: Glad it helped. :)